# Already Existing User in MVC3 razor

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing project MVC3 razor  whaen I was inserting the data that would be saved in database.If the user is already in database  that username should't be saved in database and one error msg has to be displayed how can I write the code for this?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You open up your favourite code editor and type away.  Unless you don't have fingers - in which case I don't know.

(Anticipating -1's)

*In all seriousness, though (and this should be a comment but because I've added an answer I'm going to put it here) - how can you expect anybody here to give you a straight answer to this question.  You have not supplied any code, no information about your database schema, you haven't shown what you've tried (so we're assuming you've tried nothing).  Ultimately this is a type of question repeated many many times here on SO and it always gets treated the same way - occasionally sarcastic comments  - and I really do try not to do that any more, so sorry on this occasion - and closed within approximately 5 minutes.*